# convert excel file into prn gives different language data

Tags: excel, vba

after converting my sheet into prn it gives error during upload on my erp ,when i convert prn into txt format i saw some kind of chinese written how to fix this problem.   below code add value +1 in row "A" and convert into prn

```
Sub CONVERT()

Dim vcounter As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Sheets
  ws.Activate
  vcounter = 2
  While Range("A" & vcounter).Value <> ""
    Range("a" & vcounter).Value = Range("a" & vcounter).Value + 1   
    vcounter = vcounter + 1
  Wend
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".prn"
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts` is turned off then never turned back on. Don't forget about restoring the setting once you've completed the Sub.

Answer (score 2):

You're saving a .xlsm/.xlsx file with a .prn extension; that doesn't make it a .prn file, it's still a .xlsm/.xlsx file - the extension isn't what determines the file's format, it's just a convenient indicator for us puny humans to recognize what we're looking at when we browse through files. You want to supply a `xlTextPrinter` [XlFileFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) argument to the [`SaveAs` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.saveas):

```
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".prn", xlTextPrinter
```

---

A note about this:

```
ws.Activate
```

You don't need it. Instead, qualify these `Range` calls with the `ws` object - and you want to iterate the `Worksheets` collection (`Sheets` may contain all kinds of non-worksheet sheet types):

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ' or did you mean to iterate sheets in ThisWorkbook?
    Do While ws.Range(...)
        ws.Range(...) = ws.Range(...) + 1
        vcounter = vcounter + 1
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.SaveAs FileName:="..." & ws.Name & ".prn", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
Next
```

Comment: I want to save my file in PRN and my code is working awesome but the problem is once you convert the output prn then convert into notepad  all the data i have put in my excel came into some other language it like ----  (ƒÑ}q’ne”:½ŒA¯[÷ &QâÐÄ6–ö'o?“Cº@É.¡............

Comment: All your code is doing is sticking a .prn extension to a file that contains .xlsx data. Whatever is reading .xlsx data while expecting .prn data, is reading gibberish because of that. You need to specify the `FileFormat` argument in the `SaveAs` method call. It's not "some other language", it's literal gibberish, a byte soup.

Comment: @RISHABHSINGH What you're reading in Notepad is .xlsx content, i.e. a zip-compressed file. Specify the `FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter` when you `SaveAs`, and then the data should be as expected.

Comment: @RISHABHSINGH Your code is the equivalent of `copy MyWorkbook.xlsx MyDatabase.accdb`. Just because you changed the extension from `.xlsx` to `.accdb` does NOT mean that Access will now be able to open it as an Access Database file. You've simply done `copy MyWorksheet.xlsx MyWorksheet.prn` - it's still an Excel file, not a text file. By setting the `FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter` as recommended in this answer, you're telling Excel to save plain text instead of Open Workbook XML.

Comment: One last thing i have used your code it is working a fine(ws.SaveAs Filename:="D:\birla soft\" & ws.Name & ".prn", FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter) but it gives output like this (...sheet1,...sheet2) I do not want (...) these dots in the starting i just want and keep it simple like (sheet1) (sheet2) & so on.

Comment: @RISHABHSINGH the code in this answer was never meant to be copy-pasted directly. I didn't feel like spelling out the whole file names, you can do that and fill in the blanks.

Comment: Ooops sorry i became so lazy or you an say clumsy. by the way thanks a lot